# PHP XPath, cannot retrieve text after tags inside targeted tags

Tags: php, xpath

I have this html code, to do xpath on it:

```
<b>Random Field:</b>
<p>
   A random field describes an <a href="/index.php?page=glossary&term_id=230">
   experiment</a> with outcomes being functions of more than one continuous variable, 
   for example U(x,y,z), where  x, y, and z are coordinates in space. Random field is 
   extension of the concept of <a href="/index.php?page=glossary&term_id=598">random 
   process</a> into the case of multivariate argument.
</p>
```

I tried this to take the text inside the `<p>` tag:

```
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($curl_scraped_page);
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
print $xpath->evaluate('string(//p[preceding::b]/text())');
```

But it just gave me this:

```
A random field describes an
```

What I want is:

`A random field describes an ..(an so on until).. of multivariate argument.`
So I'm guessing the problem lies on the `<a>` tag. Cause every time I tried to do this on the same-patterned document, it stops right before this `<a>` tag.
Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
$xpath->query('//p[preceding::b]')->item(0)->textContent;
```

There's a `string-join` function in XPath, but sadly not in the XPath 1.0 version in lbxml which PHP uses.

Comment: Thank you ^^ What's the difference between evaluate and query? What does item(0) mean there? Thanks..

Comment: `evaluate()` will return a typed result (nodelist, string, integer,etc.) result if possible, `->query()` always returns a `DOMNodeList`, `->item(0)` gets the first (0-indexed) item from that list, in this case the sole (first) `<p/>` element. If there are _more_ `<p/>` nodes you wish to capture, you'd loop through the DOMNodelist that `->query()` returns & concatenate the `->textContent` of the items in there 'manually'.